# SQL Group By field. Grouping items by split row code

Tags: javascript, c#, sql

I have table like this

| Name | Code |
| --- | --- |
| John | 0 |
| Sam | 01 |
| Jack | 011 |
| Bill | 02 |
| Parent | 1 |
| Some1 | 11 |
| Some2 | 111 |
| Some3 | 112 |
| Some4 | 1111 |

Is that posible group data in SQL like this?

```
[
    {
        Name: 'John',
        Code: '0',
        children: [
            {
                Name: 'Sam',
                Code: '01',
                children: [
                    { Name: 'Jack', Code: '011' }
                ]
            },
            {
                Name: 'Bill',
                Code: '02'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Name: 'Parent',
        Code: '1',
        children: [
            {
                Name: 'Some1',
                Code: '11',
                children: [
                    {
                        Name: 'Some2',
                        Code: '111',
                        children: [
                            { Name: 'Some4', Colde: '1111' }
                        ]
                    },
                    { Name: 'Some3', Code: '112' }
                ],
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Or is it better to do it on JS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate nested nth level JSON SQL Server using recursive CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69053148/generate-nested-nth-level-json-sql-server-using-recursive-cte)

Comment: But yeah, it's probably easier to do it in JS

Comment: How can you differ 111 as the 11th child of 1 from 111 as the 1st child from 11?